# css flexbox and height auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently learning Flexbox and there is something I don't understand.

My preview page shows the following:

[image]

When I write display: flex;    it shows the following:

[image]

What I can't understand is why does the height of the elements change to fill the entire container?

here is the code sample:

```css
#box-container {
  background: gray; 
  height: 500px; 
}
 
#box-1 {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
    
#box-2 {
  background-color: orangered;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: px;
  right: 0px;       
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
   <div id="box-1"><p>Hello</p></div>
   <div id="box-2"><p>Goodbye</p></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: a code sample will be nice... are you sure you don't have `flex: 1;` there too?

Comment: I suggest, Look this tutorial, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ .

Comment: Browser default setting: `align-items: stretch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's flex default, if you set display to flex:

- Items display in a row (the flex-direction property's default is row).
- The items start from the start edge of the main axis.
- The items do not stretch on the main dimension, but can shrink.
- **The items will stretch to fill the size of the cross axis**.
- The flex-basis property is set to auto.
- The flex-wrap property is set to nowrap.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#the_flex_container

Answer (score 0):

That's because the default settings are like that. But if you don't want it, you can add `align-items: flex-start;` to the flex container:

```css
#box-container {
  background: gray;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#box-1 {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#box-2 {
  background-color: orangered;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
  <div id="box-1">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box-2">
    <p>Goodbye</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

(note: The distance between the first and second child element is due to your `left: 200px;` and `position: relative` settings on the second child element)